# UNNotificationAction not showing actions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have following code that display notification. It's work, however, it's not showing action buttons. I wonder what could be wrong?

```
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];


    UNAuthorizationOptions options = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound;

    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:options
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                              if (!granted) {
                                  NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
                              }
                          }];

    // Objective-C
    UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
    content.title = @"Don't forget";
    content.body = @"Buy some milk";
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

    // Time
    UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:30
                                                                                                    repeats:NO];

    // Objective-C
    NSString *identifier = @"UYLLocalNotification";
    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier
                                                                          content:content trigger:trigger];

    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
        }
    }];


    // Actions
    UNNotificationAction *snoozeAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"Snooze"
                                                                              title:@"Snooze" options:UNNotificationActionOptionNone];
    UNNotificationAction *deleteAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"Delete"
                                                                              title:@"Delete" options:UNNotificationActionOptionDestructive];

    // Objective-C
    UNNotificationCategory *category = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:@"UYLReminderCategory"
                                                                              actions:@[snoozeAction,deleteAction] intentIdentifiers:@[]
                                                                              options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionNone];
    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:category];

    // Objective-C
    [center setNotificationCategories:categories];

    // Objective-C
    content.categoryIdentifier = @"UYLReminderCategory";
```

Comment: try to add teh notification after you set up the actions so the "center addNotificationRequest .." should be the last call from your code

Answer (score 1):

You created the **UNNotificationRequest** before you fully configured your **UNMutableNotificationContent** by setting its *notificationCategories* & *categoryIdentifier*.

Just move the following lines to the end of your code should solve your problem:

```
NSString *identifier = @"UYLLocalNotification";
UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier
                                                                      content:content trigger:trigger];

[center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
    }
}];
```

And since simulator does not support 3D Touch, it would be better to test it on a real device. When you see the notification, force touch it and you should see the action buttons.